# How to locate the Android Resource Name for Firebase Test Lab Presets

Tags: react-native, appium, firebase-test-lab

WE are planning to use the Firebase Test Lab to test our mobile app written in React Native. For Android testing presets we need to provide the user name and password resource names and values for the test to crawl through the app. Howver we could not find the right values to use for the user name and password resouce names.

For example we tried with login_password, R.string.login_password and @string/login_password for the password. None worked.

In appium tests we use @AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//*[@resource-id='login_password']") without any issue but it doesn't work in with the Firebase Test preset. The testID set for that field is 'login_password'.

Can someone shed some light on what to be used there.

Firebase Test lab test to login to the app and crawl through it to figure our possible testing paths.